# Unity launcher made with Alacarte iconless

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop, alacarte

trying to create a launcher with a .png image file and main menu keeps on removing it. is .png not supported or do I need to edit the image first?

Comment: .png icons can be used, could you post your file (launcher)?

Comment: I have no idea how I would post my launcher. it's just a main menu launcher for minecraft

Comment: Open the file with gedit (or drag it onto a gedit window), copy its content and paste it into your question. (click on "edit below your question). I can look for errors.

Comment: when I right click it in the unity launcher and in main menu it doesb't have an openwith option. in main menu it only has properties and in the unity launcher the onyl option is to remove it from the launcher/

Comment: I mean on the .desktop file itself where is it stored? There is probably a small error in the file.

Comment: what .desktop file? I said I used main menu. there isn't anything on my desktop

Comment: Your post sais you try to create a launcher; how?

Comment: with main menu, alacarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What goes wrong

I tried to create a launcher with Alacarte, with the same result. It turns out that when Alacarte creates a new launcher, it does not handle the icon's file extension correctly on custom icons. In the `Icon=` line of the launcher; it simply leaves out the extension.

#### How you can fix it

In your home directory, there is a folder `~/.local/share/applications` (`.local` is invisible by default, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to make it visible). That is the location where your launcher (file) is created.

- Open the folder
- Look for a file named `alacarte-made.desktop` (if you created more than one, they will be numbered)
- Open gedit, drag the file `alacarte-made.desktop` on to the open gedit window to open it.
- Look for the line, starting with `Icon=`, replace the section after `Icon=` with the path to your icon, *including* the `.png` extension.

#### Note

You might have to log out and back in to see the result.

Comment: I did and it already had the right path.

Comment: @SyiKargath Then could you paste the content of the file in your post? Alacarte consequently removes the extenion.

Comment: Icon=/home/randy/Pictures/minecraft_icon_by_dharmainitiative2010-d33ca5p

Comment: I don't see a `.png` extension, like I mentioned in my answer. I assume it is in the icon's name.

Comment: so just add the .png and it should work?

Comment: if the icon's name is `minecraft_icon_by_dharmainitiative2010-d33ca5p.png`, absolutely. As mentioned, you might have to log out/in before you see the result.

Comment: not only did it not work but logging out froze my machine. I forced a shutdown and now my mouse pointer is nowhere to be found

Comment: Then something else is wrong with your system. There is no way editing a .desktop file like I explained can cause trouble like this.

Comment: so, I feel very dumb but which one should I be editing? alacarte-made.desktop, alacarte-made.desktop~, alacarte-made-1.desktop?

Comment: @SyiKargath The one ending with `~` is just a gedit backup file, don't edit that one! It looks like you made more than one launcher; To see which one is "the right one", you can right-click, go to "properties", then "permissions" tab, then tick "allow to execute". Now you can see/recognize the file, named as you named it.