# Eclipse/STS no icon when launched

Tags: icons, .desktop

I've created a `.desktop` file looking like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=sts
Comment=Spring Tool Suite
Icon=/home/pago/Programi/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/pago/Programi/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/STS
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;Eclipse
StartupWMClass=STS
```

The desktop file has the correct icon, but when it launches it's just a red x sign in a grey frame. I also tried putting the `.desktop` icon in `~/.local/share/applications/sts.desktop` and in `/usr/share/applications/sts.desktop`
and I've copied the icon to `/usr/share/pixmaps/sts.xpm`

Even if I search in activities for STS and pin it to dash, it has a normal icon, but when launched it defaults to the wrong one.

Comment: What is the output when you open STS, then open a terminal and type `xprop WM_CLASS` and click with the mouse cursor (which should have changed into a crosshair now) on the STS window? (related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558098/icon-missing-when-application-is-launched)

Comment: I tried that too, forgot to mention it. Weirdly I can't select it with xprop.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Gnome Desktop and Wayland make sure to use the proper value for  StartupWMClass in your sts.desktop - file (tested with STS 3.9.9).

1. Log out
2. [Switch to an Xorg-Session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. Start STS
4. Open a terminal and enter **xprop WM_CLASS**
5. Place the crosshair over your STS-Window and click
6. Enter the displayed value (e.g. *WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Spring Tool Suite 3
   ", "Spring Tool Suite 3
   "*
   ) as StartupWMClass in your sts.desktop file (e.g. *StartupWMClass=Spring Tool Suite 3*)
7. Log out and switch back to wayland session

Answer (score 0):

Add this file in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`.

See [this](https://gist.github.com/josdem/5d1686946520fb617cdf).

sts.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=sts
Comment=Spring Tool Suite
Icon=/home/josdem/STS/sts-3.7.3.RELEASE/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/josdem/STS/sts-3.7.3.RELEASE/STS
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=STS
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04LTS using the Gnome DE

Put your desktop file in `/home/username/.local/application` then it'll show up in applications menu (<kbd>super</kbd> a.k.a "The Windows key" on the keyboard to access)

Fom there you can right click and chose <kbd>Add to favorites</kbd>.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1054609/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04 I did below and worked.
I did it for SpringToolSuite4.

Run the below command in terminal:

**`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/STS.desktop`**

Above should open gedit.
Paste below in the file and save:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Spring Tool Suite 4
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Comment=Spring Tool Suite 4
Exec=/Path_To_STS/SpringToolSuite4
Icon=/Path_To_STS/icon.xpm
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

Immediately after that, I see the icon in my Applications section:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For 2022 STS the executable has changed. Working for me:

In terminal :

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sts.desktop
```

Can also save it in your home directory without sudo priviledges :

```
 gedit ~/.local/share/applications/sts.desktop
```

The file contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=STS
Comment=Spring Tool Suite
Icon=/d/apps/ide/sts/sts-4.14.0.RELEASE/icon.xpm
Exec=/d/apps/ide/sts/sts-4.14.0.RELEASE/SpringToolSuite4
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Spring Tool Suite
```

In spring STS About :

> Spring Tool Suite 4
>
> Version: 4.14.0.RELEASE
>
> Build Id: 202203131612
>
> OS: Linux, v.5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.24.30
>
> Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
>
> Java runtime version: 17.0.2+8
>
> Java version: 17.0.2